# Hashing a list of email addresses in SQL

Tags: sql, hash, sha256

I have a list of around 40,000 email addresses. I need to hash them using SHA-256 & generate an individual hash for each email address. I've been told that I can do this via SQL but after a lot of Googling & trying to guess my way through it as a layperson I haven't had any success.

Comment: Do you know any programming lanugages?

Comment: What OS will you be using?

Answer (score 3):

In many SQL variants including MySQL, Redshift, Postgresql you can do this using the `md5()` or `FUNC_SHA1()` functions.

For example using md5:

```
SELECT md5(email) AS uid
from schema.table;
```

In PHP you can use the `md5()` or `sha1()` functions

```
sha1($email);
```